# What is the purpose of using conditional statements to activate a function?

Tags: c++, function

What is the purpose of activation a function like so

```
if(!FUNCTION()){
  return(1);
}
```

Why not call the function like

```
FUNCTION();
```

Although I am using the conditional statement in the initialization of the application and really causes no system cluttering at all, would it not be faster to just call `FUNCTION()`?

I know the conditional also has a return of 1, but isn't the return also unnecessary?

I am using this like so in this snippet:

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCMDline, int nCmdShow){
    //HWND initialization
    if(!InitMainWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow)){
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error codes.

If the `FUNCTION` returns anything other than 0, the wrapping one will return 1 signaling an error. This is handy to use with `init()` functions, as idioms such as `if(init() != S_OK) printf("error");` are quite common. A little bit of C knowledge explains why the ` != S_OK` can easily be left out in the if statement.

Comment: @Shark, he wrote: "if(!FUNCTION())", so 1 will be retured only if FUNCTION() does return zero.

Comment: @JimRhodes same thing as most people/devs use negative error codes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose is to check the return value from `FUNCTION`.  Presumably, `FUNCTION` is declared something like this:

```
bool FUNCTION();
```

Where the return value (`bool`) indicates success or failure.  Suppose you have a function that connects to a database:

```
bool ConnectToDatabase();
```

`ConnectToDatabase` will *try* to connect to the database, but in real code bad things happen, and functions don't always succeed.  If we take this code in a larger context:

```
ConnectToDatabase();
databasePointer->GetTheTable();
```

You can see if we weren't able to connect to the database, trying to attach to a table within it will never succeeed, and in fact the database pointer, `databasePointer`, might not even be valid.  Trying to attach to a table in an unconnected database sill surely only end in tears.

So we check to make sure that the functions we call do what we expect, before moving on with code that assumes that they did:

```
if (!ConnectToDatabase())
  return false
databasePointer->GetTheTable();
```

The example code you posted is much the same, but with some twists:

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCMDline, int nCmdShow){
    //HWND initialization
    if(!InitMainWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow)){
        return 0;
}
```

`InitMainWindow` in this case is possibly a function that does more than one thing:

1. It creates the main window.
2. It waits until the user has finished using the main window
3. After the main window has been closed, the `InitMainWindow` returns

So here you see the call to `InitMainWindow` might take minutes or hours before it returns, and when it does return it is time for the program to exit.

On the other hand, `InitMainWindow` might be as simple as that -- it just inits the main window and returns immediately.  In that case, we don't want to start using that window if `InitMainWindow` failed for some reason.

Comment: This. Good job writing this on a somewhat realistic example. +1

Answer (score -1):

Calling the function in this manner allows you to feed the result into a similar, but more complicated construct.

For example, lets say you had a function:

```
int somefunc(){
    if (!otherfunc())
        return 1;
}
```

Then you could feed the result into another if statement.

```
if (somefunc())
    // Do Something meaningful
```

Technically, this code has an error because if InitMainWindow returns non-zero, WinMain will not have a return value, though that is often ignored for main functions.

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCMDline, int nCmdShow){
    //HWND initialization
    if(!InitMainWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow)){
        return 0;
}
```